# Permission denied AngularCLI installation Could not read from remote repository

Tags: angular, permissions, command-line-interface, failed-installation

I am trying to install Angular CLI in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS but I take this error . I have various solutions approaches but i didn't solve it . Some of them  are

- I tried to add github to known hosts
- I created RSA keys for github
- Uninstall and install Node.js

Every try that i make with every way to access github response this message : Permission Denied (public key)

```
[sudo] password for efti: 
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:angular/cli Cloning into bare repository '/home/efti/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-angular-cli-515723dd'...
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:angular/cli Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:angular/cli fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:angular/cli 
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:angular/cli Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:angular/cli and the repository exists.
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install angular/cli
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, stat 'angular/cli'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-169-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! cwd /home/efti/.ssh
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path angular/cli
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/efti/.ssh/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clone with https: `git clone https://github.com/angular/angular-cli.git`.

But if you want to install the angular-cli global on your system, you have to run `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

Comment: I tried both . The error that i attached is from pm install -g @angular/cli.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I guess it was due to an old or buggy installation of node. I solved by uninstalling and reistalling node (I did it with brew install node). After that it worked fine.